# IPC on linux and mac with dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, ipc, named-pipes

How can I pass data from one process to another in dotnet framework on Mac and Linux? I evaluated Named pipes but due to the restrictions on non windows platform mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/ApiCompat), I am looking at other alternatives.

Any suggestions? The processes are both on the same machine.

```
Unsupported Members
Member                            Unsupported on
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRights    non-Windows
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule      non-Windows
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAuditRule       non-Windows
System.IO.Pipes.PipesAclExtensions  non-Windows
System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity        non-Windows
```

Comment: Sticking to sockets for now.